# Select most recent from multiple columns and combine into a single field

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a table where I'm trying to get the lastest date from either field b or field c per user. and then combine that into a single field.  Using MS Access 2016

Example.

| USER | FieldB | FieldC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | 2/1/2020 |
| 2 | 1/1/2020 | - |
| 3 | - | 3/1/2020 |
| 4 | - | - |

And I need the data returned in like this.

| USER | FieldB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/1/2020 |
| 2 | 1/1/2020 |
| 3 | 3/1/2020 |
| 4 | - |

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

EDIT:  Got it to work with the following query. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution.

```
SELECT
USER, Max(FieldB) as FieldD
FROM ( SELECT
       USER, FieldB
       FROM Table
       UNION
       SELECT
       USER, FieldC
       FROM Table) as T1
GROUP BY USER
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for assisting with the MarkDown formatting @MattiaRighetti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way without using UNION

```
SELECT Table.User, IIf(FieldB>FieldC,FieldB,FieldC) AS NewField
FROM [Table];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
USER, Max(FieldB) as FieldD
FROM ( SELECT
       USER, FieldB
       FROM Table
       UNION
       SELECT
       USER, FieldC
       FROM Table) as T1
GROUP BY USER
```

This is the answer i eventually figured out, would still appreciate a more elegant answer.